# how to get id which is defined after "type": "Feature" on feature select.?

Tags: php, google-maps, open-source, openlayers, layer

how to get id which is defined after "type": "Feature" on feature select.?first i set it as u see.
then  i try to get this id alert(e.feature.id),it gives me like this OpenLayers.Feature.Vector_2345

```
var featurecollection = { 
          "type": "FeatureCollection", 
            "features": [ 
            <?php for($i=0;$i<$size_of_loop;$i++){ ?>
            { 
                "type": "Feature",
                id:"<?php echo $i ?>", 
                "geometry": 
                    { 
                      type: "Polygon",                                                
                       coordinates: 
                        [[                                                                
                            <?php 
                                echo $var[$i];
                            ?>
                        ]] 
                     }, 

             },
            <?php }?>                                
          ] 
       };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alert(featurecollection.features[0].id);`

Edit if you want to iterate to it, or make it dynamic:

```
for(var i = 0; i <featurecollection.features.length; i++) {
    var id = featurecollection.features[i].id;
}

function getFeatureId(var index) {
    if(typeof(index != 'undefined') && index > 0)
        return featurecollection.features[id].id;
}
```

Comment: yes it is helpfull but how can make it dynamically , because it gives only zero index value on feature select

Comment: i just wanna call this on feature select as it is doing already but wrong like this " OpenLayers.Feature.Vector_2345"..if i write ur code in my prgram it shows nothing

Comment: @ShababakramRaja Would you please add the code to your question instead of to my answer??!?

Comment: Mr Rob it is not allowing me to paste complete code here,it gives formating error